# Prove that if $\left | g \right |=n $ is finite then $\lvert g^m \rvert=\frac{n}{(m,n)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $\left | g \right |=n $ is finite then $\lvert g^m \rvert=\dfrac{n}{(m,n)}$

Don't know where to even start.... :( help plz

I think i'm suppose to use Lagrange's theorem, but im not sure.
$(m,n)$ is it the gcd of m and n in this case?
The source did not specify whether g is an element of a group G, but my assumption that it is.

Comment: Please put the full question in the body. And please provide all the context. I assume $g$ is an element of some group? And yes, $(m,n)$ is probably the gcd. But on the other hand, since you are the one asking the question, you should be in a better position to find out (since you know where this is from).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $1 = (g^{m})^{t} = g^{mt}$ for some $t > 0$. Then $n \mid m t$. This implies, by a simple arithmetic fact, that
$$
\frac{n}{(m,n)} \mid t.
$$
Now note that 
$$(g^{m})^{{n}/{(m,n)}} = (g^{n})^{{m}/{(m,n)}} = 1.$$